# Add Access Point to Sonicwall TZ100

Tags: router, wifi, sonicwall, access-point

I have a [SonicWall TZ-100](http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/SonicWALL_TZ_100_200_Series_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf) configured with two private networks, 192.168.1.x LAN and 192.168.10.x WLAN. The WLAN is bridged to the WAN so traffic goes direct out through the WLAN and never access our internal LAN. SonicWall DHCP is enabled for the WLAN.

I have a [Ubiquiti UniFi AP](http://amzn.com/B004XXMUCQ) that I'd like to add to extend the coverage of the WLAN.

How can I configure the TZ100 to get the AP on the 192.168.10.x network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup an additional zone (LAN2) and assigned that to x4. the W0 WLAN interface was set to layer 2 bridge mode to the x4. Now both the WLAN and the x4 were on the same network.

The next issue I had was getting traffic from LAN 2 to flow to the WAN. First, I disabled any firewall access between WLAN/LAN2 -> LAN/VPN/DMZ. Then I added Any to Any access between LAN2 <-> WAN. After than I had to add a static route for the x4 interface to the W